# Scaling an image affects other elements around the targeted image

Tags: css

Basically what I'm trying to do it to have a set of images in a row, and whenever I hover over one of them that image should be enlarged and get a red border.

I'm using CSS transitions for this.

My problem right now is that when I hover over an image, all the surrounding images gets pushed down and a little bit to the side.

One thing I've noticed is that if I remove the border transition the effect works perfectly.

The html part is very simple:

```
<div id="Menu">
    <img src="img1" alt="" /> <img src="img2" alt="" /> <img src="img3" alt="" /> <img src="img4" alt="" /> <img src="img5" alt="" /> <img src="img6" alt="" /> <img src="img7" alt="" />
</div>
```

As for the CSS:

```
#Menu {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:20px;
}
#Menu img {
    position:relative;
    display:inline;
    border:none;
    transform:scale(1);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    -moz-transform:scale(1);
    z-index:1;
    transition:transform .5s, border .5s;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .5s, border .5s;
    -moz-transition:-moz-transform .5s, border .5s;
}
#Menu img:hover {
    position:relative;
    display:inline;
    border: 3px #C00 solid;
    border-radius: 2px;
    transform:scale(1);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.3);
    -moz-transform:scale(1);
    z-index:10;
    transition:transform .5s, border .5s;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .5s, border .5s;
    -moz-transition:-moz-transform .5s, border .5s;
}
```

What's the problem and how do I fix it?

[Here's a JsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/N9Zdq/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add

```
#Menu img {
   border: 3px solid transparent;
}
```

Explanation:

If you learn about CSS box-model architecture

[image]

Border takes up space around the element and not inside the element, so when you use the border on hover, it actually takes up space around the element and pushes other elements aside, and hence inorder to prevent that, we spoof up that place using border with a transparent color.

If you want you can also use new CSS3 property, which is called `box-sizing: border-box`

Complete Cross Browser

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
box-sizing: border-box;
```

What does this do?

The borders, paddings etc will be counted inside the box instead of calculating outside, so you can also use these properties if you don't need `transparent` border

Answer (score 2):

simple put border transparent

```
#Menu img {
border: 3px solid transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N9Zdq/2/

Comment: he's supposed to get bigger to :p

Comment: `+1` but you should really explain _why_ it solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N9Zdq/4/)

here take a look at the fiddl`e`
you were scaling to 1, which he already was. I changed it to 1.3 :)