# Scale Bootstrap Column on Hover

Tags: css, zooming, css-transforms

I've been trying to create a zoom, pop out effect for a group of grid boxes in Bootstrap 3. The problem I am having is the zoom effect is causing the bottom columns to be pushed down since there is height being added. Is there a way to have the boxes directly on top of grid items without pushing the others down?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-programs row">
    <div class="col-program col-md-3 clearfix">
      <h2>Program Title</h2>
      <div class="col-button">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-program col-md-3 clearfix">
      <h2>Program Title</h2>
      <div class="col-button">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-program col-md-3 clearfix">
    <h2>Program Title</h2>
    <div class="col-button">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-programs row">
    <div class="col-program col-md-3 clearfix">
      <h2>Program Title</h2>
      <div class="col-button">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-program col-md-3 clearfix">
      <h2>Program Title</h2>
      <div class="col-button">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-program col-md-3 clearfix">
    <h2>Program Title</h2>
    <div class="col-button">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row-programs .col-program {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 250px;
  background-color: #EDEDED;
  zoom: 1;
  transition: zoom 1.5s ease;
}
.row-programs .col-program h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
.row-programs .col-program:hover {
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  zoom: 1.1;
}
.row-programs .col-program .col-button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
}
.row-programs .col-program .col-button .btn {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/codesnippetsguru/pen/jWEBmM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scaling an image affects other elements around the targeted image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561534/scaling-an-image-affects-other-elements-around-the-targeted-image)

Comment: don't you use transform:scale(x); ?? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrxZML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this satisfy you? (no transition for zoom since it would cause layout jumps)

```
   &:hover {
      margin-top: -10px;
      margin-bottom: -15px;
      background-color: lighten(#EDEDED, 5%);
      transition: background-color .4s ease-in-out;
      z-index: 1;
      zoom: 1.1;
    }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbEmKd